# Selecting the content of a sibling in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, attributes, fancybox, siblings

I'm trying to get the value of the sibling of a certain link in jQuery, but I'm not sure how to select it. Here's my HTML code.

```
<figure>
    <a class="figure" href="http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/img/package_control/install_package.png"><img src="http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/img/package_control/install_package.png" title="Something"></a>
    <figcaption>
        Great Picture Description. Original by <a href="http://www.example.com/">Random person</a>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

I want to display the content from the `figcaption` inside the `figure`. The actual code I have is using the `title` property from the link.

```
$(obj).attr('title')
```

Thanks for your support

Comment: i don't understand your question. `figcaption` IS inside `figure`. http://jsfiddle.net/cgPfM/

Comment: You question makes no sense. Please revise.

Comment: I am assuming that you want to use the content of `figcaption` as the title of fancybox, don't you? what version of fancybox?

Comment: @JFK The latest version, and yes, you are right about what I said :)!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hVEfC/

```
var content = $('figure figcaption').html();
alert(content);​
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your title, (but not your question) here is the selector for the [next sibling](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/):

```
$('.figure ~ figcaption').
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to use the content of `figcaption` as the fancybox `title` .... so with the same `html` above and for fancybox **v2.x** try this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var newCaption;
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".figure").fancybox({
  afterLoad: function(){
   newCaption = $(this.element).next('figcaption').html();
   this.title = newCaption
  }
 }); // fancybox
}); // ready
</script>
```

If you want to change the `title` type, use the `helpers` option like

```
helpers: {
 title : {
  type : 'inside'
 }
}
```